# Selenium Jar Files for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jar

I am trying to run the below code
package JavaBasics;

---

```
enter code here
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class OpenBrowserURL {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\Pooja\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/?ccde=us");
}
}
```

---

I am getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for get as the jar files that i downloaded 3.141.59 has get as void

How can i fix this? Is this an issue with the jar files I downloaded. Please advice

Comment: Is this a Maven project ?

Comment: No...I am trying it in eclipse IDE just a practice project

Comment: It would be very easy if you do it using Maven

Comment: Ok..can you give me any pointers? I can try it

Comment: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/getting-started-with-maven-for-selenium-testing/